# R - Working on Speed / Efficiency - Creating + Updating a Matrix from a large file

Tags: r, performance, matrix, apply

Ill start with my intuition - I presume there is some way to do this using "apply" without looping over every single entry in my file, but I cannot figure it out.

I have a very large file. Around 4,000,000 rows, 6 columns.  For the sake of this discussion, only 3 of those columns are relevant.  They are `day`, `grade1` and `grade2`

I want to create a matrix with multiple fields, using those 3 columns from my .txt mentioned above.

I want `day`, `grade1Wins`, `grade2Wins`, `ties`, `grade1Score`, `grade2Score`, `grade1Avg` and `grade2Avg`.  These are all per day.

So my output matrix will have those 8 columns, and rows equal to the number of days that there are.

I define these as follows.

`Grade1Wins` : Starts at 0, increment by 1 for each row where `Grade1` > `|Grade2|`.
`Grade2Wins` : Starts at 0, increment by 1 for each row where `|Grade2|` > `Grade1`.
`ties` : Starts at 0, increment by 1 for each row where `Grade1` == `|Grade2|`

`Grade1Score` : Summation of raw score values.
`Grade2Score` : Summation of raw score values.

`Grade1Avg :`Grade1Score`/ (numRows)`
Grade2Avg : `Grade2Score` / (numRows)

I want this all as a matrix.  So, for example, my data may look like....(subset to only show the 2 relevant columns)

```
Day    Grade1    Grade2
1    2         -4
1    4         -4
2    10        -1
```

So my output matrix would be

```
`day` `grade1wins` `grade2wins` `ties` `grade1score` `grade2score` `grade1avg` `grade2avg`
  1        0           1          1         6           -8             2          -4
  2        1           0          0         10          -1             10          -1
```

Currently, I do this via loops.
My matrix is pre-defined (# cols / # rows determined in advance, have a blank matrix full of 0's waiting for editting).

I loop through every row of my tab-delimited .txt file.

I determine the day of the current row.  This is my row number.
I pull the values from the row for `grade1` and `grade2`.

```
#Loop over every single row.
for(i in 1:len)
{
            entry = entries[i,]
            rowNum = entry$day
            if( entry$grade1> abs(entry$grade2) )
            {
                mat[rowNum, "grade1wins"] = mat[rowNum, "grade1wins"] + 1 ## Increment the counter 
            } else if( abs(entry$grade2) > entry$grade1 ) {
                mat[rowNum, "grade2wins"] = mat[rowNum, "grade2wins"] + 1 ## Increment the counter 
            } else {
                mat[rowNum, "ties"] = mat[rowNum, "ties"] + 1
            }

            mat[rowNum, "grade1"] = mat[rowNum, "grade1"] + entry$grade1
            mat[rowNum, "grade2"] = mat[rowNum, "grade2"] + entry$grade2
} # end loop, we went through every single entry now
mat[, "PosAvg"] = mat[,"PosScore"] / mat[, "NumTweets"]
mat[, "NegAvg"] = mat[,"NegScore"] / mat[, "NumTweets"]
```

I presume there is some way to do this using "apply" without looping over every single entry in my file, but I cannot figure it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with the help of `data.table` package.

You can read the dataset with the help of `fread()` function and save the dataset to a variable, say data2.

Now, you can apply the desired operation by this code:

```
test_function <- function(dt){
    grade1wins <- length(which(dt$Grade1 > abs(dt$Grade2)))
    grade2wins <- length(which(dt$Grade1 < abs(dt$Grade2)))
    ties <- nrow(dt) - grade1wins - grade2wins
    grade1score <- sum(dt$Grade1)
    grade2score <- sum(dt$Grade2)
    grade1avg <- mean(dt$Grade1)
    grade2avg <- mean(dt$Grade2)

    return (list(grade1wins = grade1wins,grade2wins = grade2wins,
        ties = ties,grade1score = grade1score,grade2score = grade2score,
        grade1avg = grade1avg,grade2avg = grade2avg))
}

> as.matrix(data2[,test_function(.SD),by=Day])
     Day grade1wins grade2wins ties grade1score grade2score grade1avg grade2avg
[1,]   1          0          1    1           6          -8         3        -4
[2,]   2          1          0    0          10          -1        10        -1
```

Comment: While I won't be able to try it until tomorrow likely, this is a beautiful solution. May I ask a follow-up question regarding the by=Day?  Some of my datasets, instead of daynumbers have timestamps in the posix format YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.  Is it possible to still do the sort-by day for each day?  So if I had a file for say, January, I'd end up with 31 rows, each corresponding to a different day?

Comment: Actually, I figured it out ( as.POSIXct( day, format="%Y-%m-%d") ), but I do have 2 other questions about what your solution is doing.   What exactly is that .SD?  Also, all of my matrix values come up quoted.  Adding quotes=FALSE and stringsAsFactors=FALSE does not fix it. Any idea what is happening?

Comment: @Jibril As far as .SD is concerned in this context, it is **S**ubset of data2's **D**ata for each group formed by Day. In other words, it is similar to 'splitting the entire dataset in terms of distinct values of Day' and then selecting each splitted dataset one by one. For more details, you may refer to `?data.table`

Comment: Coming to your second question, the values are coming out as quoted because a matrix can have elements of only one type. It may be vector, numeric , character and so forth. As POSIXct is more of a character representation, all the elements are converted to somewhat character representation resulting quotes.

Comment: Beautiful! I decided to stay up late and give it a shot, and this worked beautifully! Code that was taking well over an hour before is now finishing in seconds. Thank you so much!